# Finding just the searched string in all files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is is possible to find a specific string in all files and just display the string instead of line in which search result. I have got a huge project with some css tag starting with a string. Would like to find number of css tags starting with those pattern string. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

There is an example

```
File One
This is a sample <div class="myapp-bold">Text</div>
File Two
This is a sample <div class="myapp-small myapp-bold">Text</div>
```

In results, I would like to see

```
File One
myapp-bold
....
File Two
myapp-small myapp-bold
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `grep`, not SublimeText.

Answer (score 1):

You can search!! 
1)Drag and drop your project folder to sublime.
2) Press ctrl+shift+ F
3) enter the search value in Find:
4) click on Where: and add the complete folder where you want to search